# How to reset password by phone number using firebase auth

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication, reset-password

I'm currently developing an e-commerce website using PHP. My website allows users to create an account using phone number. And the phone number is authenticated using firebase Auth. I'm using mysql database to store the informations of the user after they signed up for an account, including the phone number of user. I'm trying to figure out how to implement a password reset. So when the user clicked on "forgot password" on my page, it will require them to keyin their phone number, an authentication code number will be sent to their registered phone number. After the phone number is authenticated, a rest password page will be shown to the user to require them to change their password.

I'm not using any platform to create my website just pure php, html and JavaScript.

The only reset password functionality I can found on the firebase is using email address. Is there any where I can implement what I've stated above?